# How to connect to the switch console port?

Tags: macos

I download the [PL2303 Mac Driver](http://www.prolific.com.tw/US/ShowProduct.aspx?p_id=229&pcid=41).

In the manual, it seems the `step 3` I did not meet:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

---

My case:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

I don't know the telephone number and account name fill what, who can tell me about this?

Comment: What will you use the modem for

Comment: @Mark i want to connect to switch through its console port.

Answer (score 1):

Taking into account your other three posts today, on similar subject, I think you need the free application [CoolTerm](http://freeware.the-meiers.org), and do the configurations there. It is similar with putty from Windows.

FYI: Apple computers are way different in terms of drivers compared with Windows, PL2303 driver is already part of Apple drivers, so no need to install such ones.

A similar question/answer is [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/257795/usb-to-serial-on-macos-sierra-not-working/257854#257854)

Comment: > NOTE: v1.4.7 is the last version of CoolTerm available as a universal binary supporting OS X 10.6 or older, click here to download.   my OS X version is 10.12, does it support?

Comment: Yesterday I checked the last version, it is 1.5.8, if I remember well. And works on High Sierra.

Comment: It's 1.5.0, where did you find the `1.5.8`?